# Is there a way to create a notification in the Notification Center with a clickable link?

Tags: applescript, notifications

I can create a notification in Applescript via

`display notification "Notification Text" with title "Title goes here" subtitle "subtitle goes here`

However is there a way when I click on the notification it will take me to a url?  I tried setting the notification text to something like "https://apple.stackexchange.com/" however that didn't work.

Comment: I might try wraping the url in an `a` tag next

Comment: Nope it won't work, it doesn't interpret HTML.

Comment: Similar to [this question and the answers indicates that you can be redirected to a url](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50395/how-do-i-display-a-hyperlink-with-an-applescript).

Answer (score 3):

What you ask isn't possible with bare AppleScript.

There are 2 possibilites I'm aware off :

- Using [Terminal Notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) : A CLI binary which will allow you to create notifications
- Using [Notification scripting](http://www.cooperative-fruitiere.com/notifications/index_en.html) : A .app which can be called with AppleScript to create notifications.